# What should return from a disjunction with independent variables?

Tags: prolog

What would result from something like the following:

```
p(X,Y) :- q(X).
p(X,Y) :- r(Y).
q(a).
r(b).
```

I don't have a Prolog compiler handy, so I can't test what would happen if you then asked `p(X,Y)`.  Would the code even compile?  Would `p` return two answers, each with one of the variables unbound?

In a real world scenario, I don't think `p(X,Y)` would make much sense (one would probably rather want `p(X)` to follow from either `q(X)` or `r(X)`), but I'm interested in what actually happens here, and peripherally, what *should* happen in such a degenerate case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Would p return two answers, each with one of the variables unbound?*

Yes. You need to type a ; to see further solutions:

| ?- p(X,Y).

X = a ? ;

Y = b

yes
| ?-

This agrees with the theory, where an unbound variable means that any value can be substituted for this variable.

Answer (score 1):

so.p contains:

```
p(X,Y) :- q(X).
p(X,Y) :- r(Y).
q(a).
r(b).
```

---

```
$ gprolog
GNU Prolog 1.3.0
By Daniel Diaz
Copyright (C) 1999-2007 Daniel Diaz
| ?- consult('so.p').
compiling /home/jboker/Desktop/so.p for byte code...
/home/jboker/Desktop/so.p:1: warning: singleton variables [Y] for p/2
/home/jboker/Desktop/so.p:2: warning: singleton variables [X] for p/2
/home/jboker/Desktop/so.p compiled, 5 lines read - 506 bytes written, 8 ms

yes
| ?- p(X,Y).

X = a ?

yes
```